# Variable is being reset and im not sure why? c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am clicking a button to hide one window and open another.

```
private void gamemodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    background.moduleNumber = 1;
    this.Hide();
    moduleScreen showForm = new moduleScreen();
    showForm.Show();
    MessageBox.Show(background.moduleNumber.ToString()); //for checking that the variable was applied
}
```

The text property of a label will change in the new form depending on what button is clicked. This is done by assigning a value to a public variable depending on what button is clicked.

```
public class backgroundProgram
{
    public int moduleNumber;
}
```

This is the code that changes the text on the label according to the variable:

```
private void moduleScreen_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (background.moduleNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            moduleLabel.Text = "Game Design 1 - CGP1005M";
            break;
        case 2:
            moduleLabel.Text = "Algorithms and Complexity - CMP 1124M";
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Nope");
            break;
    }
}
```

So far the variable background.moduleNumber is resetting to 0 before it enters the switch/case, so i only get the default case back every time. Any ideas?

Edit: Just added a watch to the variable and it gets wiped on this line.

```
  private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

This lies in moduleScreen.Designmer.cs

code showing my new backgroundProgram(); location

```
namespace ModNote
{
public partial class moduleScreen : Form
{
    static backgroundProgram background = new backgroundProgram();
    public moduleScreen()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += moduleScreen_Shown;
    }

    public void moduleScreen_Shown (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (background.moduleNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                moduleLabel.Text = "Game Design 1 - CGP1005M";
                break;
            case 2:
                moduleLabel.Text = "Algorithms and Complexity - CMP 1124M";
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Nope");
                break;
        }


        }
```

}
}

Comment: How does the `moduleScreen` WinForm receive the the `backgroundProgram` object? Do have a static instance of that? I don't see any problems with the code.

Comment: yes:  static backgroundProgram background = new backgroundProgram();

Comment: In what class is this defined? It must be defined in only one. If the `moduleScreen_Show()` is in a different class than `gamemodeButton_Click()` the access to that static variable should look something like `SomeClass.background.moduleNumber`. The fact that it resets to zero sounds like you're recreating that object and it gets the default `int` value (0).

Comment: Im still not sure on how the changing of the forms can reset the background.moduleNumber value though?

Comment: Add a watch to the variable and make it break when the value changes

Comment: @Durell It depends on where your `new backgroundProgram()` call is.  Just because the variable is static doesn't mean that the object it references can't change.

Comment: @Durell I don't think it deliberatly clears your variable in the `moduleScreen.Designer.cs`, it just happens to be cleared on creating a new insance of the `moduleScreen` class. Can you show us the place (or places) where you declared your static variable?

Comment: where should my new backgroundprogram(); be placed in order for this to work? - updated main post with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and the post I deduce that you have a sitation like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    static backgroundProgram = new backgroundProgram(); //first declaration

    private void gamemodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundProgram.moduleNumber = 1;
        //rest..
    }
}
```

And then in the other class

```
public partial class moduleScreen : Form
{
    static backgroundProgram = new backgroundProgram(); //second declaration

    public void moduleScreen_Shown (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       switch(backgroundProgram.moduleNumber) 
       {
          //...
       }
    }
}
```

However, although the variables have been declared `static`, each class holds one *different* static instance of the objects for itself. In `MainForm` and `moduleScreen` you are refering to "backgroundProgram", which are different objects from the point of view of these two classes. You must either pass your object from one `Form` to another or you can just use a seperate class in which you declare the property `static` from the beginning.

Passing the reference would go like:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    static backgroundProgram = new backgroundProgram(); //first declaration

    private void moduleScreen_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundProgram.moduleNumber = 1;
        moduleScreen showForm = new moduleScreen();
        showForm.backgroundProgram = backgroundProgram; //give it this object
        //rest..
    }
}

public partial class moduleScreen : Form
{
    public backgroundProgram; //no initialization. null from the beginning, set later.

    public void moduleScreen_Shown (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       switch(backgroundProgram.moduleNumber) 
       {
          //...
       }
    }
}
```

Or, with a static field:

```
public class BackgroundProgram
{
    public static int moduleNumber; 
}

public partial class moduleScreen : Form
{
    //no own static fields of that object
    public void moduleScreen_Shown (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       switch(BackgroundProgram.moduleNumber) //Refer to the static field of that class
       {
          //...
       }
    }
}
```

And in that other class:

```
    private void gamemodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundProgram.moduleNumber = 1; //Refer to that same static field.. 
        //..
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely possible to say form the given code, but from what I see it looks as though you are creating a new moduleScreen every time the button is pressed